# How can I add a column to an existing model in Magento after an existing field?

Tags: magento

I am creating a Magento module that makes use of a new column in `sales/quote`.

I know how to use `addAttribute` and `addColumn` respectively, but I can't figure out how to put the SQL equivalent of `AFTER column` from the entity model classes.

Also, do I need to always `addAttribute` to the corresponding model after `addColumn` to a table?